# How to make audio call using local range Wifi?

Tags: android, audio, wifi, call

I want to make an app which can do audio call between 2 android phones. I do not want to use SIP as its functionality is to make calls using internet anywhere. But i want to make simple app like In a office, everyone using the same WiFi router can communicate.
Please don't suggest me SIP. 
I know, using peer to peer, we can send packets but can it make audio call??
Is there any other way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the data transfer based on UDP protocol.

Presence of noise may create some interference in the communication.

[Here](https://github.com/DeanThomson/android-udp-audio-chat)  is a complete demonstration of Audio Chat Android Application using UDP packets.

You can receive as well as call a particular contact.

All the peoples in the same network (using the application) will listed when you came to main Activity.

Comment: Thanks for help, Let me check if it works. I need to change only EXTRA_IP from code or something more?

Comment: There is no need to change anything.Just install the APK in 2 android devices which should be connected to the same network via WIFI. Go ahead.

Comment: oh yeah...m stupid.. That was string for intent. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Don : The app is working fine, the connections are being made correctly. But there is a screeching noise at both ends. I tried changing the buffer value as well as SAMPLE_RATE, but still no change. Can you please point me to some resources to explain why this distortion?

Comment: UDP data transmission is not reliable .Obviously noise will come

Comment: It is not working for, can somebody please help me out?